# Function doesn't exist - jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I did jQuery function which will open when user clicks on image. I don't Know where's a problem. Console says - "gost_registracija.php:343 Uncaught ReferenceError: _hsync_promijeni_skin is not defined"

Here's code.

```
<img onclick="_hsync_promijeni_skin(<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinovi_rasaB[$_id]; ?>)" .... >

<input type="hidden" id="_hsync_trenutni_skin_id" name="_hsync_skin" value="<?php echo $_hsync_skin; ?>">

    function _hsync_promijeni_skin(_skinid)
    {
        alert("Promijenio si skin!");
        $('#skin_'+ $( "#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id" ).val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");
        $('#skin_'+ _skinid +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_"+ _skinid +".png");
        $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", _skinid);
        $('#_hsync_skins_menu').modal('toggle');
    }
```

Comment: Is the function definition in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Try to debug by removing the php inside your onclick function. then inside the script try to put an alert. To ensure everything works fine. I it does then it's in your php problem. And make sure the function is enclosed inside the `<script>` tag

Comment: If it's in a `<script>`, make sure it's defined at the top level, not inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Now it Works, half. Two lines below alert don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Barmar was right.
Now, everything works fine, only these two lines don't work.

```
    $('#skin_'+ $( "#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id" ).val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");
    $('#skin_'+ _skinid +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
```

Code needs change classes so user can see which skin he picked up.

Comment: Fixed it. Problem was in img tag.

Answer (score -1):

Just add quotes in php tag:

```
<img onclick="_hsync_promijeni_skin('<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinovi_rasaB[$_id]; ?>')" .... >
```

Comment: It's complaining that the function doesn't exist, not about a syntax error.

Comment: have you put function inside <script> tag  and outside $(document).ready ?

Comment: That comment should be on the original question, it doesn't have anything to do with this answer. And I already asked those same exact questions in my comments.

Comment: I also don't know why you're asking me that question, I'm not the author of the question.

Comment: oh sorry..didn't noticed the name.